# ruby on rails passing block instead of argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I have a rails 4 app. For recognizing links I'm using the `rinku` gem. Now I'm trying to integrate `best_in_place` gem for inline editing. On my `post_comment.body` attribute I'd like to use both at once, but can't figure out how to make them work together.

Original code with `rinku` only:

```
<%= find_links(h post_comment.body) %>

#And the corresponding method:

def find_links(text)
  found_link = Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, 'target="_blank"', skip_tags=nil).html_safe
end
```

It would look like this with `best_in_place` only:

```
<%= best_in_place post_comment, :body, as: :input, url: post_post_comment_path(post_comment.post, post_comment), activator: "#activate-comment-edit-#{post_comment.id}" %>
```

Now the way I tried to combine, but got wrong number of args error:

```
<%= find_links do %>
  <%= best_in_place post_comment, :body, as: :input, url: post_post_comment_path(post_comment.post, post_comment), activator: "#activate-comment-edit-#{post_comment.id}" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I make this work? What is the ruby/rails conventions in these kind of cases? I guess I should pass in a block somehow, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, if you don't pass anything into `find_links`, and it expects an argument, that kind of makes sense, doesn't it? If `find_links` expects the output of `best_in_place` then why wouldn't you pass the result of that call to `find_links`?

Comment: Dave, could you show it with the code? I mean it would look weird to pass the whole line of code into the argument.

Comment: Would it? Why can't you save it into a variable, and pass that variable in? I'm not really sure what the issue is, I guess.

Comment: Dave there is no real issue as you say, I just thought there would be a more elegant solution and I wanna use the rails conventions instead of some shitty code. Can you pls tell me how you would do that? I mean in which file would you put the variable (application helper, etc.) and what kind of variable it would be (local, etc.)? Sorry for asking this way, I just like code examples with file names, since that's explicit and I can't misunderstand the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this depending on what you're trying to achieve. This is one way.

```
def find_links(text = nil)
  if block_given?
    text ||= yield
  end
  raise ArgumentError, 'missing text' unless text
  found_link = Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, 'target="_blank"', skip_tags=nil).html_safe
```

Alternatively, you could have your method explicitly capture the block:

```
def find_links(text = nil, &block)
  text ||= block.call if block
  raise ArgumentError, 'missing text' unless text
  found_link = Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, 'target="_blank"', skip_tags=nil).html_safe
```

To clarify, you can't really "pass a block into a method". Every time you use a block it is being passed to the method. Your method needs to explicitly `yield` to the block or it needs to capture it to a `Proc`. The difference is that a `Proc` has an evaluation context bound to it.

And to be complete: you ***can*** pass a `Proc` into your method (just like you would any other variable) but it is more idiomatic to use `yield` like above

Comment: Josh, thanks for the detailed answer! Why do you set the arg nil (`text=nil`)? I also would like to use this method for other models where I only pass `(h message.body)` for example. So it should work if I pass just an attribute or if I pass this best in place code.

Comment: `text = nil` here means give `text` a default value of `nil` (i.e. it's optional). We have two entry points into the method (pass in `text` or eval the block). If we didn't make `text` optional then we'd have to pass it along with a block in that use case